# Why are the results of Cplex and PythonDocplex different

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

My results of Cplex and PythonDocplex are different.I feel confused and donot know why.
Here are my code.They are very long because of having data.Their data is same and constraints correspond to each other.And you can run both of them directly.
Because I cannot submit for no detail,I will add some useless words.Please understand.Thank you.
PythonDocplex:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

model = Model()

I2 = list(i for i in range(1, 11))  #
S2 = list(s for s in range(1, 9))  #
T2 = list(t for t in range(1, 10))  #
B2 = list(b for b in range(1, 45))  #
K2 = list(k for k in range(0, 10))  #
model.I1 = I2
model.S1 = S2
model.T1 = T2
model.B1 = B2
model.K1 = K2
I = model.I1  #
S = model.S1  #
T = model.T1  #
B = model.B1  #
K = model.K1  #

I1 = 10
S1 = 8
T1 = 9
B1 = 44
K1 = 9

V0 = [16, 16, 15, 14, 15, 13, 15, 15, 16, 14]
h = 14
d1 =[[11,31,19,43,11,19,43,31],
[15,27,15,39,15,15,39,27],
[11,23,11,35,11,11,35,23],
[11,19,11,31,11,11,31,19],
[15,15,15,27,15,15,27,15],
[19,11,11,23,19,11,23,11],
[23,11,11,19,23,11,19,11],
[27,15,15,15,27,15,15,15],
[31,11,19,11,31,19,11,11],
[35,11,23,11,35,23,11,11]]

R = [[4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[8,8,8,4,4,0,0,0,0],
[8,8,8,8,4,4,0,0,0],
[0,0,8,8,8,8,4,4,0],
[4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,8,8,8,8,4,4]]

H =[[0,0,0,20,20,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,20,20,0,0,0,0,0],
[20,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

G = {1:[[0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      2:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,3,5,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,6,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      3:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,6,2,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,5,3,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,2,6,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      4:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      5:[[0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      6:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      7:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      8:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
}

D = {1:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,3,2,2,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,4,3,2,3,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      2:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      3:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      4:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      5:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,5,1,1,3,2,0,0,0],
[0,2,4,3,1,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      6:[[0,0,4,2,2,1,2,1,0,0],
[0,3,3,2,3,2,1,2,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      7:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      8:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
}

P = {1:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      2:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      3:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      4:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      5:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      6:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      7:[[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0],
[1,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],
[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],
      8:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
}

L = {1: [[0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]],
      2:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      3:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      4:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      5:[[0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0]],
      6:[[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      7:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
      8:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
}

var_list_A = [(i, s, t) for i in I for s in S for t in T]
var_list_B = [(i, t) for i in I for t in T]
var_list_C = [(i, s, t, k) for i in I for s in S for t in T for k in K]  # Variable
GA = model.integer_var_dict(var_list_C, lb=0, name='GA')  # Variable
DA = model.integer_var_dict(var_list_C, lb=0, name='DA')  # Variable
GB = model.integer_var_dict(var_list_A, lb=0, name='GB')  # Variable
DB = model.integer_var_dict(var_list_A, lb=0, name='DB')  # Variable
PA = model.integer_var_dict(var_list_A, lb=0, name='PA')  # Variable
LA = model.integer_var_dict(var_list_A, lb=0, name='LA')  # Variable
M = model.integer_var_dict(var_list_A, lb=0, name='M')  # Variable
N = model.integer_var_dict(var_list_A, lb=0, name='N')  # Variable
V = model.integer_var_dict(var_list_B, lb=0, name='V')  # Variable
var_list = [i for i in range(1, 10)]
a = model.integer_var_list(var_list, lb=0, name='a')  # Variable
b = model.integer_var_list(var_list, lb=0, name='b')  # Variable
c = model.integer_var_list(var_list, lb=0, name='c')  # Variable
d = model.integer_var_list(var_list, lb=0, name='d')  # Variable

for s in S:
    for t in T:
        model.add_constraint(R[s-1][t-1] == model.sum(GB[i, s, t] for i in I))  #

for s in S:
    for t in T:
        model.add_constraint(H[s-1][t-1] == model.sum(DB[i, s, t] for i in I))  #

for s in S:
    for t in T:
        for k in K:
            if k <= T1-t:
                model.add_constraint(G[s][t-1][k-1] == model.sum(GA[i, s, t, k] for i in I))  #

for s in S:
    for t in T:
        for k in K:
            if k <= T1-t:
                model.add_constraint(D[s][t-1][k-1] == model.sum(DA[i, s, t, k] for i in I))  #

for s in S:
    for i in I:
        for t in T:
            model.add_constraint(GB[i, s, t] == model.sum(GA[i, s, t, k] for k in K if k <= T1-t) + M[i, s, t])  #

for s in S:
    for i in I:
        for t in T:
            model.add_constraint(DB[i, s, t] == model.sum(DA[i, s, t, k] for k in K if k <= T1-t) + N[i, s, t])  #

for s in S:
    for i in I:
        for t in T:
            model.add_constraint(PA[i, s, t] == model.sum(DA[i, s, t-k, k] for k in K if 0 < k < t)+P[s][i-1][t-1])  #

for s in S:
    for i in I:
        for t in T:
            model.add_constraint(LA[i, s, t] == model.sum(GA[i, s, t-k, k] for k in K if 0 < k < t)+L[s][i-1][t-1])  #

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        model.add_constraint(model.sum(DB[i, s, t]+LA[i, s, t] for s in S) >= a[t-1])  #

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        model.add_constraint(model.sum(DB[i, s, t]+LA[i, s, t] for s in S) <= b[t-1])  #

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        model.add_constraint(model.sum(GB[i, s, t]+PA[i, s, t] for s in S) >= c[t-1])  #

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        model.add_constraint(model.sum(GB[i, s, t]+PA[i, s, t] for s in S) <= d[t-1])  #

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        model.add_constraint(model.sum(DB[i, s, t]+LA[i, s, t] for s in S) <= h)  #

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        model.add_constraint(model.sum(GB[i, s, t]+PA[i, s, t] for s in S) <= h)  #

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        if t == 1:
            model.add_constraint(V[i, t] ==
                                 model.sum(GB[i, s, t]+DB[i, s, t]-PA[i, s, t]-LA[i, s, t] for s in S)+V0[i-1])  #
        if t >= 2:
            model.add_constraint(V[i, t] ==
                                 model.sum(GB[i, s, t]+DB[i, s, t]-PA[i, s, t]-LA[i, s, t] for s in S)+V[i, t-1])  #

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        model.add_constraint(V[i, t] <= B1)  #

for t in T:
    model.add_constraint(b[t-1] <= h)  #
for t in T:
    model.add_constraint(d[t-1] <= h)  #

#choose one of them(fc1,fc2)
fc1 = model.sum(b[t-1] - a[t-1] for t in T) + model.sum(d[t-1] - c[t-1] for t in T)
# fc2 = model.sum((DB[i, s, t] + GB[i, s, t]) * d1[i-1][s-1] for i in I for s in S for t in T)
model.minimize(fc1)

sol = model.solve(clean_before_solve=True, log_output=True)
print(sol.solve_details)
print(sol)
```

Cplex:

mod:

```
range I = 1..10;
range S = 1..8;
range T = 1..9;
range B = 1..44;
range K = 0..9;
int T1 = 9;//
int B1 = 44;//
int h = 14;//
int V0[I]=...;//
float d1[I][S]=...;//
int R[S][T]=...;//
int H[S][T]=...;//
int G[S][T][K];//
int G1[T][K]=...;//
int G2[T][K]=...;//
int G3[T][K]=...;//
int G4[T][K]=...;//
int G5[T][K]=...;//
int G6[T][K]=...;//
int G7[T][K]=...;//
int G8[T][K]=...;//
int D[S][T][K];//
int D1[T][K]=...;//
int D2[T][K]=...;//
int D3[T][K]=...;//
int D4[T][K]=...;//
int D5[T][K]=...;//
int D6[T][K]=...;//
int D7[T][K]=...;//
int D8[T][K]=...;//
int P[I][S][T];//
int P1[I][T]=...;//
int P2[I][T]=...;//
int P3[I][T]=...;//
int P4[I][T]=...;//
int P5[I][T]=...;//
int P6[I][T]=...;//
int P7[I][T]=...;//
int P8[I][T]=...;//
int L[I][S][T];//
int L1[I][T]=...;//
int L2[I][T]=...;//
int L3[I][T]=...;//
int L4[I][T]=...;//
int L5[I][T]=...;//
int L6[I][T]=...;//
int L7[I][T]=...;//
int L8[I][T]=...;//
execute {
  for(var i in I)
      {
        for( var s in S)
        {
          for(var t in T)
          {
            for(var k in K)
            {
             if(s=1)
             G[s][t][k]=G1[t][k];
             D[s][t][k]=D1[t][k];
             P[i][s][t]=P1[i][t];
             L[i][s][t]=L1[i][t];
             if(s=2)
             G[s][t][k]=G2[t][k];
             D[s][t][k]=D2[t][k];
             P[i][s][t]=P2[i][t];
             L[i][s][t]=L2[i][t];
             if(s=3)
             G[s][t][k]=G3[t][k];
             D[s][t][k]=D3[t][k];
             P[i][s][t]=P3[i][t];
             L[i][s][t]=L3[i][t];
             if(s=4)
             G[s][t][k]=G4[t][k];
             D[s][t][k]=D4[t][k];
             P[i][s][t]=P4[i][t];
             L[i][s][t]=L4[i][t];
             if(s=5)
             G[s][t][k]=G5[t][k];
             D[s][t][k]=D5[t][k];
             P[i][s][t]=P5[i][t];
             L[i][s][t]=L5[i][t];
             if(s=6)
             G[s][t][k]=G6[t][k];
             D[s][t][k]=D6[t][k];
             P[i][s][t]=P6[i][t];
             L[i][s][t]=L6[i][t];
             if(s=7)
             G[s][t][k]=G7[t][k];
             D[s][t][k]=D7[t][k];
             P[i][s][t]=P7[i][t];
             L[i][s][t]=L7[i][t];
             if(s=8)
             G[s][t][k]=G8[t][k];
             D[s][t][k]=D8[t][k];
             P[i][s][t]=P8[i][t];
             L[i][s][t]=L8[i][t];
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }                                                                                                         
dvar int+ GA[I][S][T][K];//Variable
dvar int+ GB[I][S][T];//Variable
dvar int+ DA[I][S][T][K];//Variable
dvar int+ DB[I][S][T];//Variable
dvar int+ PA[I][S][T];//Variable
dvar int+ LA[I][S][T];//Variable
dvar int+ M[I][S][T];//Variable
dvar int+ N[I][S][T];//Variable
dvar int+ V[I][T];//Variable
dvar int+ a[T];//Variable
dvar int+ b[T];//Variable
dvar int+ c[T];//Variable
dvar int+ d[T];//Variable
//choose one of them(fc1,fc2)
dvar float+ fc1;
//dvar float+ fc2;                                                                                                      
minimize fc1;
//minimize fc2;

subject to
{
fc1 == sum(t in T)(b[t]-a[t])+sum(t in T)(d[t]-c[t]);
//fc2 == sum(i in I, s in S, t in T)((DB[i][s][t]+GB[i][s][t])*d1[i][s]);
//
forall(s in S, t in T){
  R[s][t]==sum(i in I)(GB[i][s][t]);
}
//
forall(s in S, t in T){
  H[s][t]==sum(i in I)(DB[i][s][t]);
}  
//
forall(s in S, t in T, k in K:k>=0&&k<=T1-t){
  G[s][t][k]==sum(i in I)(GA[i][s][t][k]);
}
//
forall(s in S, t in T, k in K:k>=0&&k<=T1-t){
  D[s][t][k]==sum(i in I)(DA[i][s][t][k]);
}
//
forall(i in I, s in S, t in T){
  GB[i][s][t]==sum(k in K:k>=0&&k<=T1-t)(GA[i][s][t][k])+M[i][s][t];
}
//
forall(i in I, s in S, t in T){
  DB[i][s][t]==sum(k in K:k>=0&&k<=T1-t)(DA[i][s][t][k])+N[i][s][t];
} 
//
forall(i in I, s in S, t in T){
  PA[i][s][t]==sum(k in K:k>=0&&k<t)(DA[i][s][t-k][k])+P[i][s][t];
}
//
forall(i in I, s in S, t in T){
  LA[i][s][t]==sum(k in K:k>=0&&k<t)(GA[i][s][t-k][k])+L[i][s][t];
}
 //       
forall (i in I, t in T){
  sum(s in S)(DB[i][s][t]+LA[i][s][t])>=a[t];
}
//
forall (i in I, t in T){
  sum(s in S)(DB[i][s][t]+LA[i][s][t])<=b[t];
} 
//
forall (i in I, t in T){
  sum(s in S)(GB[i][s][t]+PA[i][s][t])>=c[t];
}
//
forall (i in I, t in T){
  sum(s in S)(GB[i][s][t]+PA[i][s][t])<=d[t];
}
//
forall (i in I, t in T){
  sum(s in S)(DB[i][s][t]+LA[i][s][t])<=h;
} 
// 
forall (i in I, t in T){
  sum(s in S)(GB[i][s][t]+PA[i][s][t])<=h;
}
//
forall (i in I, t in T:t>=2&&t<=T1){
V[i][t]==sum(s in S)(GB[i][s][t]+DB[i][s][t]-PA[i][s][t]-LA[i][s][t])+V[i][t-1];
}
//
forall (i in I, t in T:t==1){
V[i][1]==sum(s in S)(GB[i][s][t]+DB[i][s][t]-PA[i][s][t]-LA[i][s][t])+V0[i];
} 
//
forall (i in I, t in T){
  V[i][t]<=B1;
}
//  
forall(t in T){b[t]<=h;
}
//
forall(t in T){d[t]<=h;
}
}
```

dat:

```
V0 = [16, 16, 15, 14, 15, 13, 15, 15, 16, 14];
d1 = [[11,31,19,43,11,19,43,31],
[15,27,15,39,15,15,39,27],
[11,23,11,35,11,11,35,23],
[11,19,11,31,11,11,31,19],
[15,15,15,27,15,15,27,15],
[19,11,11,23,19,11,23,11],
[23,11,11,19,23,11,19,11],
[27,15,15,15,27,15,15,15],
[31,11,19,11,31,19,11,11],
[35,11,23,11,35,23,11,11]];
R = [[4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[8,8,8,4,4,0,0,0,0],
[8,8,8,8,4,4,0,0,0],
[0,0,8,8,8,8,4,4,0],
[4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,8,8,8,8,4,4]];
H = [[0,0,0,20,20,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,20],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,20,20,0,0,0,0,0],
[20,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
G1 = [[0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
G2 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,3,5,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,6,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
G3 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,6,2,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,5,3,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,2,6,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
G4 =[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
G5 = [[0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
G6 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
G7 =[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
G8 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
D1 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,3,2,2,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,4,3,2,3,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
D2 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
D3 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
D4 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
D5 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,5,1,1,3,2,0,0,0],
[0,2,4,3,1,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
D6 = [[0,0,4,2,2,1,2,1,0,0],
[0,3,3,2,3,2,1,2,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
D7 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
D8 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
L1 = [[0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]];
L2 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
L3 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
L4 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
L5 = [[0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0]];
L6 = [[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
L7 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
L8 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
P1 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
P2 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
P3 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
P4 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
P5 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
P6 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
P7 =[[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0],
[1,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],
[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]];
P8 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a precision: you are asking about a difference between two versions of a model, one written in OPL, and one in Python DOcplex,so your post should be tagged with "opl" too.

In order to get the same results from OPL and DOcplex, you must check the following points:

- make sure you use the same platform, i.e. machine/OS/OS version (e.g. Windows 10)
- make sure you use the same version of Cplex (e.g. 12.10)
- make sure variables and constraints are declared in the same order: a diferent ordering may cause different results
- make sure you use the same Cplex *parameters* (e.g. time limit, mip emphasis, etc.)

If all above points are OK and you still get different results, export the model to LP format, both from OPL and DOcplex and check that the two LP files are identical.

Comment: Thank you for your help.But I don't know how to export the model to LP format from DOcplex.Can you tell me the details?Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: Use  `Model.export_as_lp(path, basename)`; Path default is a temp dir, use '.' to write in current directory, basename default is model name. For example: `Model.export_as_lp(path='.', basename='my_model')` will write `mymodel.lp` in current directory. There is also the `lp_string` property to access a string with LP representation.